# Why Confirm Prompting Again And Again?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using Jquery ajax call to delete my html table. everything is fine but alert message is showing gain and again.

what am I doing wrong?

**Delete button**

```
"<a href='#my_modal' class='delete-Record'>Delete</a></td></tr>";
```

**document.ready**

```
 $(document).on("click", ".delete-Record", function () {
                DeleteRecord();
            });
```

**Jquery function**   Updated Code

```
 function DeleteRecord() {
        $(document).on("click", ".delete-Record", function () {
            var UserIDD = $(this).closest('tr').children('td .width10p').text();
            var params = { UserID: UserIDD }
            var ans = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this Record ?");
            if (ans == true) {
                //var params = { 'refId': refId };
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    data: JSON.stringify(params),
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: 'MobileUser_Login.aspx/DeleteRecord',
                    dataType: "json",
                    async: true,
                    success: OnSuccessCallDelete,
                    error: function (err) { // Added this event to capture the failed requests.
                        console.log(err);
                    }
                });
            }

            function OnSuccessCallDelete(data, status) {
                alert('Record Deleted!');
                load_DataForGrid();
            }
        });
    }
```

**web method**

```
 [WebMethod]
    public static void DeleteRecord(string UserID)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["FAV-VAConnectionStringDB"].ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand cmddelete = new SqlCommand("delete from [FAV_VS_USER_LOGIN] where USER_LOGIN = '" + UserID + "'", con);
        cmddelete.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        con.Open();
        int idelete = cmddelete.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }
```

I checked on .cs code which is hitting break point and also able to delete record from data base but alert message is appearing again and again

Comment: Remove `$(document).on("click", ".delete-Record"` from your `DeleteRecord` function, it's adding new event every time you click on `.delete-Record`, that's why it calls multiple alerts

Comment: @Justinas i did same as you suggested but i am not able to get Table ID

Comment: @Justinas     `var UserIDD = $(this).closest('tr').children('td .width10p').text();
                      var params = { UserID: UserIDD }`  here UserID coming null

Comment: do you have multiples link's with class .delete-Record?

Comment: Yes I have multiples link's but not same class  `.delete-Record`

Comment: @ak74 It's because your `this` now points to function, not to element. You should pass element to function

Answer (score -2):

I think you want to keep the click when DOM refreshed.
So we can't use "on".
Because "on" will add binding one more time for all old DOM ".delete-Record".
Live or Delegate will allow you to keep only one binding and auto-binding all new DOM after live/delegate.

using live when your jquery version < 1.7.

using Delegate when your jquery version = 1.7.

using on when your jquery version > 1.8

Example:

```
$(document).delegate(".delete-Record","click",function(){
...
});
```

So changed below(Jquery version = 1.7):

```
$(document).live("click", ".delete-Record", function () {
            DeleteRecord();
        });

function DeleteRecord() {
   //$(document).on(...
     ... ...
   //});
};
```

Comment: Please add explanation to this answer

Comment: I am not able to get this Answer can you explain in details.

Comment: Thanks for Explanation and I change my code but Confirm alert is not appearing

Comment: there is an error of the text format, I just fixed my answer.